# Why is JavaScript slower in a FireFox add-on than in a webpage loaded in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, firefox-addon

I wonder why the same JavaScript code is considerably slower in a FireFox add-on (using the Add-on SDK) than directly running in a web page loaded in FireFox.

For instance, this code:

```
function isPrime(number) {
    var i,
        prime = true;
    for(i = 2 ; i < number ; ++i) {
        if(number % i === 0) {
            prime = false;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}

function sumFirstPrimeNumbers(x) {
    var i,
        sum = 0;
    for(i = 1 ; i <= x ; ++i) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

var sum = sumFirstPrimeNumbers(15000);

console.log(sum);
```

takes less than 2 seconds to run in a webpage opened in FireFox, but takes about 15 seconds to run in a FireFox add-on.

I know the code could be better, but it is only an example to show how slow it is.

Why is it that slow in a FireFox add-on?

Is there any way to get it faster (without changing this code since it is, as I said above, only an example)?

**Update:**

It seems to be related to the Add-on SDK. I did another test: I executed the same code in an add-on which does not use the add-on SDK and the code execute in about 3 seconds.

Why such a huge difference (3 seconds vs 15 seconds) between an add-on using the add-on SDK and an add-on not using it?

Comment: When was the code being run? As the browser was under heavy load because it was starting up?

Comment: I'm probably telling a stupid thing, and surely someone will disprove me, but is it possible that the web page "caches" the results of `isPrime` while add-on doesn't?

Comment: This code was loaded when the browser starts. But I tried to run this code on a button click and it is as slow. And I don't know if there is any cache.

Answer (score 1):

There are two preferences (accessible from the `about:config` page) that control the javascript optimizations: `javascript.options.methodjit.chrome` for privileged code (extensions) and `javascript.options.methodjit.content` for untrusted code (web pages).

Some versions of Firefox ship with the former disabled by default.

Check `javascript.options.methodjit.chrome` to see if it's set to `true`.

Comment: this answer needs more detail. please explain to the OP what this pref option does, how to find it, etc. Otherwise, as it stands, the answer should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: It is true. What does it mean?

Comment: @antoyo The basic point is that the JavaScript JIT (or at least one of them; there are several in Firefox that trigger at different points) can be independently disabled in extensions and in web pages.  So it's possible that the code in the web page is being JITted and the code in the extension is not.

Comment: @antoyo since jit for chrome is already enabled there isn't much you can do. My educated guess is that certain optimizations just don't apply to chrome, no matter what. Perhaps it's worth trying web workers, which is a good idea anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a bug in current versions of firefox that prevent full JIT of javascript in addons, for details see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=913182